# Web App Manifest not parsed by Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have a [manifest.json](https://incredibleweb.github.io/pwa-tutorial/) according to the [MDN spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) and while it works correctly when browsing the website from a mobile device (add to homescreen popup shows up, theme color and icons load...etc) Chrome Dev Tools is unable to parse it. The same problem persists on Lighthouse (chrome extension).

[image: Chrome Dev Tools unable to parse manifest.json]

Has anyone seen a similar issue? I would think that the JSON is invalid however copy-pasting into [Web App Validator](https://manifest-validator.appspot.com/) it is marked correct, but when inputting the URL it giving a parse error:

`File isn't valid JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is probably a [BOM character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) issue in the `manifest.json` file.

If you have Notepad++ on your machine, try open the file, click menu "Encoding" -> "Encode in UTF8 without BOM" and then save the file.

If you don't have Notepad++, search Google for "Remove BOM character" for your favorite IDE/editor.