# Chrome does't recognize my manifest.json when I prompt "Add to homescreen" banner

Tags: google-chrome, manifest, banner, progressive-web-apps

I want to create a manifest to launch a "Add t homescreen" banner. However, it seems that chrome does't recognize my manifest file to launch the banner.

Here in the application tab in chrome debugger, the fields should be filled with the information from manifest.json

[image]
The manifest file is declared correctly, because it points to the right file. Here is the manifest.json:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the Web App Manifest is not being parsed correctly. You can validate it using the [Web Manifest Validator](https://manifest-validator.appspot.com/).

Did you check this similar question: [Web App Manifest not parsed by Chrome Dev Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277174/web-app-manifest-not-parsed-by-chrome-dev-tools)

Comment: Thank you! @Kevin

Comment: It seems that my link is not HTTP 200 ok, My link is like this: https://xx.org:1234/Folder/Folder, why is it not accepted?

Comment: I did not understand the exact setup, but the web app manifest is usually in the root so you would need to reference it as `<link rel="manifest" src="/manifest.json" />`

Comment: @KevinFarrugia does it always have to be in the root of domain?I have the web app in folder but when i run server from parent folder, the manifest of this web app in subfolder is not detected.