# The pwa app did not use the manifest icon to install in android

Tags: html, favicon, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I have set a manifest.json including icon with 192x192 png and 512x512png. When I use android and add to home screen, it just use the favicon for the app icon and the splash screen icon instead of the manifest icon. The splash icon is very small, I want a bigger logo and also using the icon set in the manifest. The manifest.json have already included in the header and Chrome Developer tools successfully detected it.

```
{
"name": "Apple",
"short_name": "Apple",
"icons": [
  {
    "src": "../images/favicon/icon-192x192.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "192x192"
  },
  {
    "src": "../images/favicon/icon-512x512.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "512x512"
  }
],
"theme_color": "#ffffff",
"background_color": "#ffffff",
"display": "standalone",
"start_url": "/apple/",
"scope": "/apple/"
```

}

I have tried to reinstall and clear website data many times but it remains unchanged.

Can anyone help? What is the pproblem? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865086/chrome-doest-recognize-my-manifest-json-when-i-prompt-add-to-homescreen-banne). One possible reason is that the Web App Manifest is not being parsed correctly. You can validate it using the [Web Manifest Validator](https://manifest-validator.appspot.com/). You may also check this [forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/pwa-manifest-not-recognized-help-with-debugging-issue/60907) on how to debug if PWA manifest is not recognized.

> There is a tool called Lighthouse ( https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse 103 ) to diagnose PWAs. See the corresponding talk from PWA Dev Summit 2016: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZjQ25NRV-E&feature=youtu.be&list=PLNYkxOF6rcIAWWNR_Q6eLPhsyx6VvYjVb